# Mule HTTP POST Request Remotely Closed error

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule-component, mule4, mule-esb

If backend system(REST API) is not closed the connection when they send the response payload as response then how can we close the connection intentionally from mule side(http request) ?

actually we found that backend system is not closing the connection so that mule is throwing 'Remotely Closed' error.

Could anyone suggest how to close the connection in Mule side(HTTP Request connector) after JUST receiving response from backend ?

And below is the HTTP configuration :

```
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_configuration" doc:name="HTTP Request configuration" doc:id="bed9482f-2a7c-4db5-91b5-6410fac08f8e" > 
   <http:request-connection host="test.com" port="81" /> </http:request-config> 

<http:request method="POST" doc:name="Request" doc:id="823ec599-3f8d-4ffa-ba03-72f33f0bc1b8" config-ref="HTTP_Request_configuration" path="/"> 
</http:request>
```

Comment: You are not providing any details. With the information you provided it is not possible to provide suggestions. Please share the XML configurations of the HTTP connector and the request operation from your Mule application, and the HTTP request from Postman (use Code / HTTP request). Also enable HTTP wire logging in Mule to capture the actual HTTP request. Kindly read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on how to improve your question.

Comment: <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_configuration" doc:name="HTTP Request configuration" doc:id="bed9482f-2a7c-4db5-91b5-6410fac08f8e" >
  <http:request-connection host="test.com" port="81" />
 </http:request-config>
<http:request method="POST" doc:name="Request" doc:id="823ec599-3f8d-4ffa-ba03-72f33f0bc1b8" config-ref="HTTP_Request_configuration" path="/">>
</http:request>

HTTP request from Postman
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: test.com:81
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 468
{
    "description": "test 123",
    "message_key": "sample123"
}

Comment: Please edit your question to add details.long comments with details are very hard to read.

Comment: Also add the payload. How are setting it in the flow?

Comment: Payload in transform message before calling HTTP Request :     %dw 2.0
output application/json
---
  {
    "description": "test 123",
    "message_key": "sample123"
}

Comment: Kindly edit your original question and add the information there.

Comment: Edited original question with proper information

Comment: Please move the information from the comments to the question.

Comment: I just modified the question with recent findings/updates

Comment: Yet you didn't add the configurations from the comments to the question.

Comment: added configuration to the question

Comment: Can anyone help on this ?